# Parse error with kprobe event registration

Tags: kprobe

I'm testing kprobe events on CentOS 7, kernel version 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64.

```
[root@linux2 ~]# echo 'p:qwe do_sys_openat2 filename=+0($arg2):string' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
[root@linux2 ~]# dmesg
[447101.144698] Parse error at argument[0]. (-22)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: DId you find what the issue was? Did you try with `filename=$arg2:string`?

Comment: @pchaigno Same result on CentOS 7

Comment: Did you try to trace it without specifying any fetch arguments? Did you confirm that symbol `do_sys_openat2` exists?

Comment: @pchaigno You're right, the symbol does not exist in kallsyms. The problem is resolved in a newer kernel version.